# Node.js/Socket.io/Passport.js LOGOUT issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I'm creating a website using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) ([Express](http://expressjs.com/) Framework) and use [Passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication. I use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for communicating between client and server. My website shows which users are online. All I want is that when client closes his tab or the browser itself without logging out of the website, I want the user to be logged out from the website when `'disconnect'` event fires. Code fragment should look like on `server` side.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('disconnect', function()  {
    console.log("|||||| DISCONNECTED ||||||");
    //LOGOUT USER CODE
});
});
```

I'm using Passportjs' local strategy. It searches for user in CouchDB database and logs in if Username/Password combination is correct.

My solution which obviously doesn't work:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
  // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
  // persistent login sessions (recommended).
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);

  //a new custom middleware to logout the user when the pathname is '/exit'      

  app.use(function(req, res, next)  {
      var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      if(pathname == '/exit')
        req.logout();
      next();
  });
});
```

I used a node module called `xmlhttprequest` defined like this to create http requests.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

and then in my socket's disconnect event I added the following lines.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('disconnect', function()  {
    console.log("|||||| DISCONNECTED ||||||");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();      
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/exit");
    xhr.send();
});
});
```

This doesn't work and the user is not logged out when `disconnect` event fires. I can see this message `|||||| DISCONNECTED ||||||` on console. Also if I enter `http://localhost:3000/exit` in my browser address bar and then press enter, I see this message: `Cannot GET /exit` in my browser but on pressing back and refreshing the page the user is logged out.

Comment: What is it not showing? What you have seems like it should work. Or have you not tried to implement anything on the server yet?

Comment: I don't know the code that should be there within the disconnect event.

Comment: I edited the question. Please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

This code is no good.

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next)  {
      var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      if(pathname == '/exit')
        req.logout();
        //try adding this line, so that it doesn't just show the "can't retrieve"
        res.end('<html><head>logged out</head><body>logged out</body></html>');
      next();
  });
```

EDIT:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function()  {
    console.log("|||||| DISCONNECTED ||||||");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();      
    //this won't work, don't do this
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/exit");
    xhr.send();
});
```

instead, do this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function()  {
    console.log("|||||| DISCONNECTED ||||||");
    user.logout();
});
```

I suggest doing a redirect from the page at this point, to exit, and have exit send another redirect to another page. It's how I would do it.

Comment: No. That's not the problem. The problem is I don't want to enter a url in my browser or click a Logout button which logs me out. I want it to happen when the disconnect event takes place.
In current scenario I'm NOT able to logout user by making a HTTP request. I'm able to LOGOUT only if enter the same url in my browser window and then press enter. And I don't want to do that.

Comment: BTW I tried your method. It gives an error.
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Oooh, ok. Also, the can't set headers is probably a issue with me putting "end", I just wanted to show that you're pretty well done at this point.

Comment: It gives me an error::::
            
ReferenceError: user is not defined

Comment: That was pseudocode... you have to define the logout process yourself.

Comment: Okay. But can you give me a link if you find it anywhere on the web. And thanks for your help.